# Conditional Search and Replace in Excel VBA

Tags: search, excel, replace, conditional-statements, vba

I'm struggling to write VBA code that will search for strings of text within cells and remove a part of the text, e.g. "John Smith QC," leaving just "John Smith," then put the removed text "QC" into the adjacent cell.

The part I'm struggling with is that I can't get the code to keep repeating until it no longer finds the text and then move on to searching for a new text, e.g. "OAM."

The code I'm trying is:

```
postnom = " QC"
postnomnew = "QC"

Cells.Find(What:=postnom, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Replace What:=postnomnew, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = postnomnew

Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
```

I can't seem to get if\endif conditional statements working and am not really sure if if\endif is the best approach.

Thanks
Ron

Comment: You could instead run a single replace on the sheet where you replace " QC" with " "

Comment: That won't enter the text into the adjacent cell though. I need to capture the text into a new column.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that part of the code...

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested but you should get the idea.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim rngTmp As Range
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim postnom As String
    Dim postnomnew As String

    Dim wksTmp As Worksheet

    postnom = " QC"
    postnomnew = "QC"
    Set wksTmp = ActiveSheet

    Set rngSearch = wksTmp.Cells

    With rngSearch
      Set rngTmp = .Find(postnom, LookIn:=xlValues)
      If Not rngTmp Is Nothing Then

        Do
          wksTmp.Cells(rngTmp.Row, rngTmp.Column + 1).Value = postnomnew
          rngTmp.Value = Replace(rngTmp.Value, LCase(postnom), "")
          Set rngTmp = .FindNext(rngTmp)
        Loop While Not rngTmp Is Nothing

      End If

    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: I've tested it now, you can get rid of the test for looping around with findnext because you're removing the postnom's and they will not be found again.  Caution about the REPLACE method because it wont catch case changes (ie QC != qc).

Comment: Thanks for the code, it returns the error compile error; wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment at .Findnext

Comment: I did say it was untested :)  I've edited it to fix the obvious error on my behalf.

Comment: I get a run time error 450, wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment on Set rngSearch = ActiveSheet.Range

Comment: changed Activesheet.Range to Activesheet.Cells